# How to correctly pass merged pdfs as _io.BytesIO object into Django FileResponse()?

Tags: python, django, pypdf, pdfmerger, fileresponse

I try to merge some pdfs with pypdf and I sadly new Document is an empty page...
Any help is apreciated! Thanks in advance!

```
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y_%H.%M")
obj_list = request.GET.getlist('PDFobj')
qs = CertificatePDF.objects.filter(id__in=obj_list)
pdfs = []
for pdf in qs:
    path = pdf.location.path
    pdfs.append(PdfReader(path))

merger = PdfMerger()
for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)
temp = io.BytesIO()
merger.write(temp)
merger.close()
temp.seek(0)

fn = f'DocuName_{str(current_time)}.pdf'
return FileResponse(temp, as_attachment=True, filename=fn)
```

I tried with HttpResponse file/attachment also... without any sucess

Comment: i have a queryset with File objects, in the first forloop, i acess each file location, appendig the paths/files to a list named "pdfs":
/apps/media/pdfs/PDF-2024-01-30_07:57.pdf
/apps/media/pdfs/PDF-2024-01-25_07:59.pdf
and so on... & they are merged
reader = PdfReader(temp)
page = reader.pages[0] -> i have played with the page indexes 
print(page.extract_text())
print(temp) -so merging works so far
i do not understand why "temp" is not converted to a valid PDF in the end...

Comment: output of "temp" <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f90628c9080>
with open(temp, "rb") as f: -> throws exception:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BytesIO

Comment: Thanks K J, your Hint was the trigger...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that the BytesIO object has to be constructed as a file, and django is able to do this... it is really simple. Here the whole method if anyone needs this in the future:

```
from django.http import FileResponse
from django.core.files import File
import io
from pypdf import PdfMerger, PdfReader
from datetime import datetime

def download_pdf_multiple(request):
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M")
    obj_list = request.GET.getlist('PDFobj')
    qs = CertificatePDF.objects.filter(id__in=obj_list)

    pdfs = []
    for pdf in qs:
        path = pdf.location.path
        pdfs.append(PdfReader(path))
    merger = PdfMerger()
    for pdf in pdfs:
        merger.append(pdf)

    temp = io.BytesIO()
    merger.write(temp)
    merger.close()
    temp.seek(0)

    fn = f'DocuName_{str(current_time)}.pdf'
    new_pdf = File(temp)
    return FileResponse(new_pdf, as_attachment=True, filename=fn)
```